# AWS Transcribe stuck in getTranscriptionJob in iOS

Tags: ios, aws-sdk-ios, amazon-transcribe

I'm trying to use AWS Transcribe in an iOS app using the aws-sdk-ios. The app starts a transcription job and I can see the job on the AWS console. But the app can't list the jobs, or get a specific job, because it gets stuck in the request to `getTranscriptionJob` or `listTranscriptionJobs`, as these requests never complete (I added a print statement and a breakpoint inside the completion block, and it never prints, nor reaches the breakpoint).

I uploaded to GitHub a sample single-view app demonstrating the problem. You'll need an AWS account or IAM user with full permissions on S3 and Transcribe. Insert that account's keys and S3 bucket in `ViewController.swift` in the appropriate variables.

https://github.com/joaomarceloods/AWSTranscribeBug

I need help. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Swift, iOS 13.2, CocoaPods, AWSCore 2.12.1, AWSTranscribe 2.12.1

Most important snippet:

```
    /// `getTranscriptionJob` repeatedly until the status is no longer `inProgress`.
    /// However, `getTranscriptionJob` never completes.
    var transcriptionInProgress = true
    while transcriptionInProgress {
        print("getTranscriptionJob")
        transcribe.getTranscriptionJob(request).continueWith { task -> Any? in
            print("getTranscriptionJob never completes...")
            let transcriptionJob = task.result?.transcriptionJob
            transcriptionInProgress = transcriptionJob?.transcriptionJobStatus == .inProgress
            return nil
        }.waitUntilFinished()
    }
    print("...after the getTranscriptionJob")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

I still don't understand why `getTranscriptionJob` freezes, but it will execute normally if you run it on `DispatchQueue.global()`:

```
.continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor(dispatchQueue: DispatchQueue.global())) {
```

Sample code diff: https://github.com/joaomarceloods/AWSTranscribeBug/commit/98e43af553413ed2bbd0c3f96e259139a991303e

Reference: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/how-to-ios-asynchrounous-tasks#executing-a-block-on-the-main-thread-with-awstask